# AngularJS stateProvider not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just beginner in angularjs. I haven't see any error and result in this below testing project.
index.html

```
<html ng-app="UserAuth">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>User Auth</title>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="controller/loginController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('UserAuth', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: "/",
                controller: "LoginController",
                templateUrl: "login.html"
            })
});
```

controller/loginController.js

```
app.controller('UserAuth', function ($scope, $http) {

});
```

My problem is login.html page is not display.

Comment: you should give correct path of `login.html` where it belongs.

Comment: find error in console. you might be need to inject dependency for state in controller

Comment: Check your developer tools in browser, probably login.html returns 404 error, `$stateProvider` doesn't need to be injected into controller

Comment: Your controller and you app share the same name - UserAuth?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, was solved
replacing

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

by

```
<ui-view>
 <i>Loading ....</i>
</ui-view>
```

Note: check also the url and controller

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to set a rule for empty route too with `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');`:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/",
            controller: "LoginController",
            templateUrl: "login.html"
        })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't have a controller named `LoginController`. You have a controller called `UserAuth`. 

You need to change

```
app.controller('UserAuth', function ($scope, $http) {

})
```

to

```
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {

});
```